# Attribute Error when extracting data from a URL with a zip file

Tags: python, zip

I am trying to access the "Yield Curve Data" available on [this page](http://www.bankofcanada.ca/rates/interest-rates/bond-yield-curves/). It has a radio button which upon clicking "Submit" results in a zip File, from which I am looking to get the data. I am looking to get the data from the "Retrieve all data" Option. My code is as follows, however, I get the error `AttributeError: read` in the line `zipfile = ZipFile(StringIO(request.read()))` and I don't know how to overcome this issue.

```
import urllib, urllib2
import csv
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import os
from zipfile import ZipFile

my_url = 'http://www.bankofcanada.ca/rates/interest-rates/bond-yield-curves/'
data = urllib.urlencode({'lastchange': 'all'}) 
request = urllib2.Request(my_url, data)
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)

zipfile = ZipFile(StringIO(request.read()))
```

Thank You

Comment: Are you sure that your request is returning what you want it to? For example, if something fails it could be set as `None` and have no `read` attribute.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan Thank You. I don't think it is failing though as `print request` gives `<urllib2.Request instance at 0x000000000920D208>` and `print result` gives `<addinfourl at 153277960L whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x00000000091CBE58>>`

Comment: If you `print result.read()` you'll see it's an html document (not ZipFile data).

Comment: @martineau I see that now, which was unexpected. Is there a way to then extract the data obtained upon clicking the "Submit" button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After deciphering the html source of the linked [webpage](http://www.bankofcanada.ca/rates/interest-rates/bond-yield-curves/), the following seemed to work — at least as far as I took it:

```
import urllib, urllib2
import csv
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import os
from zipfile import ZipFile
from pprint import pprint, pformat

my_url = 'http://www.bankofcanada.ca/stats/results/csv'
data = urllib.urlencode({"lookupPage": "lookup_yield_curve.php",
                         "startRange": "1986-01-01",
                         "searchRange": "all"})
request = urllib2.Request(my_url, data)
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
zipdata = result.read()
zipfile = ZipFile(StringIO(zipdata))
print 'zipfile.namelist(): {}'.format(zipfile.namelist())
```

Output:

```
zipfile.namelist(): ['yield_curves.csv']
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) documentation, `urllib2.Request` object has no `read` function. You should instead try - `result.read()` , as below -

```
zipfile = ZipFile(StringIO(result.read()))
```

Comment: I made a mistake. The `result` is in fact a HTML File and not a Zip File.

Comment: Maybe you should try - `http://www.bankofcanada.ca/stats/results/csv`
url , instead of your current url

Comment: Thank You. I wrote                                                  `my_url = 'http://www.bankofcanada.ca/stats/results/csv'
 result = urllib2.urlopen(my_url)
 print result
 print result.read()` to understand whats happening. But, `print result` gives `<addinfourl at 153160008L whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x0000000009218C78>>` but for some reason ` print result.read()` doesn't result in any output.

Comment: What about the zipfile creation, its still failing?

Comment: Yes it is still failing.

Comment: You will need to find out the exact path of the zip file in url and use it I believe

Comment: I actually thought of that, but don't know how to determine this exact path. Thank You.